# Page's source begins repeating after the last </html> tag, ends with a PHP error.. What?

Tags: php, html

The page in question is [budreviews.com/1-San-Diego-Holistic-Healing](http://budreviews.com/1-San-Diego-Holistic-Healing).

If you look at the source, the html seems to be repeated for some reason until PHP throws an error for redeclaring an include. Any ideas why this could happen? The page is dynamic, but no other pages generated by the same PHP page are experiencing this issue...
Any help would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

You might have some recursive includes; ie. a page that includes itself either directly or indirectly. Try changing instances of `include` and/or `require` to `inlcude_once` and/or `require_once`, respectively.

Comment: I did a sitewide search+replace, no change.The page linked is actually "/dispensaries.php?id=1", and with any other id the page works. Different id's don't call different includes, just different MySQL calls & arguments in PHP functions.

Comment: Please post some of your source code in order to get further with this.

Comment: Which particular things would you suspect to be the culprit? There's a lot of code, I couldn't post all of it.

Answer (score 0):

To find PHP errors we need to see actual PHP code.

Anyway, you have at least one of your PHP files included twice.